# Curl Request hanging in background process if computer enters sleep mode

Tags: c++, curl, networking

I am using libcurl library to send network requests to a server. This all works fine most of the time, the requests normally with no problems.

However, whilst debugging something, I realised that if the request is interrupted by the computer being put to sleep, then the request hangs.

I am yet to discover how long it will hang for, I assumed infinitely, but it did seem to release the next morning after the computer had slept for a second time when I was attempting to force the issue to replicate.

This is likely not directly an issue with libcurl, as I have seen other questions of a similar nature with requests library in Python. As a background process which relies on these network requests, what handling can I add to the curl handling to catch this issue, or prevent it in the first place?

This code already uses a timeout value for the request. This code uses curl_easy_perform to actually complete the request and the program gets stuck here. In order to force this to replicate, I entered a while true loop of sending requests to a server, then repeated again and again by putting the computer into sleep mode until the requests halted.